# Database to use for building file cataloging system

Tags: database, nosql

I'm planning on building a file cataloging system. It will do something very similar to what iTunes does for music, but only with other kinds of files.

So to clarify, the application will have a collection of files, and will store meta-data about the files in the database. For music, it would store all the artists involved in that particular song, as well as the albums the song has been released in, etc.

In order to facilitate searching through the collection of files and associated meta-data, I am considering using a database.

I'm planning on writing this programme using C++/Qt4 as a learning exercise about databases, Qt4 and good C++ coding practices.

For a task like this, what database system would you recommend. Here are the ones I have thought of using. Feel free to suggest something else.

1. MongoDB
2. CouchDB
3. SQLite
4. Tuple Store such as Redis or Raik

Perhaps in the future the application will grow into something where multiple users will be accessing the data simultaneously, so a mechanism to ensure that one user doesn't overwrite changes that have been introduced by another user would be useful (I'm thinking something similar to git's conflict resolution).

Edited title to in response to close votes.

Comment: If someone would expand on why they think this should be closed as it's too subjective, I'd be happy to try and edit the question to make it less so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo and Couch are NoSQL while SQLite is a relational solution. I think for such a task you are better off with a document DB like Couch and Mongo.

Have you seen RavenDB? Its a document DB containing conflict resolution out of the box, Map/Reduce querying and a full-text search engine. It's written in .NET but can be accessed via HTTP requests you can do quite simply in C++.

Comment: Would you elaborate on why NoSQL would be a better option for this application?

Comment: I looked into RavenDB, and althought it may be a great solution, it's dependence on .Net makes me hesitant to use it for this project, as I'm looking for a cross-platform solution.

Comment: Because nowadays when we have performing schema-less databases it doesn't make sense anymore to force entities into tables and rows. I wrote a bit more about that here http://www.code972.com/blog/2011/05/sisodb-the-wrong-solution-to-the-wrong-problems/ in a different context. And RavenDB can run on Mono.

Comment: I had actually looked up running RavenDB on Mono. Would you be able to  point out what advantages does it have over CouchDB/MongoDB for this use case.

Comment: Rob Ashton has quite lengthy discussions over those topics in his blog: http://codeofrob.com/archive/2011/01/26/ravendb-vs-mongodb-why-i-dont-usually-bother.aspx. Some things have changed since, but that should get you started. Bottom line - this seems like a fairly simple application and any DocDB will fit nicely. But once it gets more complicated (versioning, joins, auto sharding) you are going to need the largest set of features available for you, as well as many places to plug in to as possible. Have a look at each and decide for yourself which is more appealing...